# Matching one-d Array with a two-d Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having some problems grasping how to match a one-dimensional array with a two-dimensional array. So I have one array, a one-dimensional, that contains numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) and one two-dimensional array that contains numbers and some text (e.g. [1][dog], [2][cat], [3][mouse]...)

So now what I want to do is to use the first array, to see if that matches the second arrays numbers, e.g. if array[0] (contains value '1') matches array2[x] then output the array2's text, array2[x][text].

Any help is appriciated!

**EDIT:**

As per request I've exported the arrays, I don't know if that'll help, but here we go:

```
arrayX ( 0 => '1', 
         1 => '2'
)
arrayY ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'cat' ), 
         1 => array ( 0 => 'dog' )
)
```

I suppose this'd work similar to a tag system? If arrayX contains an entry with the value '1', then compare this with arrayY and output the number-match.

Comment: Can you please `var_export` the arrays and provide them in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. For `1` you want the return value to be `dog` then, right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the second array is like the following:
`$array[0]['cat'] = 'dog'`

Or `$array[0] = 'cat'`

If it's the latter, you can just iterate over the first array, outputting values from the second array like so

```
foreach ($array1 as $key) {
 echo $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array( 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 );
$arr2 = array(
            2 => array( 'text' => 'Foo', 'animal' => 'dog' ),
            3 => array( 'text' => 'Bar', 'animal' => 'cat' ),
            5 => array( 'text' => 'bla', 'animal' => 'rabbit' ),
           11 => array( 'text' => 'blub', 'animal' => 'horse' ),
           13 => array( 'text' => 'foobar', 'animal' => 'mouse' ) );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $arr1 ); $i++ )
{
    if ( isset( $arr2[$i] ) )
    {
        echo $arr2[$i]['text'] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Something like this?